# How can I check for null values within my data prior to passing onClick props?

Tags: json, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I am trying to check my data for null values before the onlCick prop is called to stop users from progressing without inputting data.
I have tried this so far but it doesn't seem to work?

```
    const [bodyDesc, setBodyDesc] = useState(null);
      const [year, setYear] = useState(null);
      const [driveType, setDriveType] = useState(null);
    
    
      <p onClick={ () =>  bodyDesc || year || driveType === null ? alert('please fill in all fields') : props.next_ClickHandler }>Next</p>
```

example of data being passed into the consts:

```
         { value: "1", label: "1" },
            { value: "2", label: "2" },
            { value: "3", label: "3" },
            { value: "4", label: "4" },
            { value: "5", label: "5" },
            { value: "6", label: "6" },

The prop handler does work on its own so that's not a problem, it just doesn't fire when all the data is set now?
```

*Edit:*
I am using a library called react-select for the drop down selects here's an example.

```
const [bodyDesc, setBodyDesc] = useState(null);

 const bodyDescOptions = [
    { value: "1", label: "1" },
    { value: "2", label: "2" },
    { value: "3", label: "3" },
    { value: "4", label: "4" },
    { value: "5", label: "5" },
    { value: "6", label: "6" },
  ];

return (
<Select
          className={"poloOption_container"}
          classNamePrefix={"poloOptions"}
          defaultValue={bodyDesc}
          onChange={setBodyDesc}
          options={bodyDescOptions}
          styles={colourStyles}
          placeholder={"Polo seies"}
        />
)
```

Comment: Don't use `const`s; Use `let` instead to declare your variables

Comment: didn't work I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want the user to be alerted when any of those values are null? The way your ternary operator is working now, is doing the opposite. Also, add a function call to the last part of the evaluation.

```
<p onClick={ () =>  bodyDesc || year || driveType === null ? alert('please fill in all fields') : () => props.next_ClickHandler }>Next</p>
```

Also, change the check for your conditional:

```
!bodyDesc || !year || !driveType
```

In JS, this will check not only for `null`, but `undefined`, `NaN`, etc

Comment: my mistake let me update the question, I did that for debugging

Comment: Even when all fields are set it still alerts instead of pushing props

Comment: Thanks mate one step closer the alert no longer pops up when the values are true but, the prop. push doesn't fire either?

Comment: Check the console, I'm sure there is an error of sorts

Comment: none that seem relevent it complains about an old API call but I don't think that related

Comment: if I change it to <p onClick={props.next_ClickHandler}>Next</p> the it runs perfectly but when its like this <p onClick={ () =>  !bodyDesc || !year || !driveType ? alert('please fill in all fields') : props.next_ClickHandler }>Next</p> the second expression doesn't run

Comment: The one you posted I did that fixed the null issue but the prop isn't firing

Comment: `() => props.next_ClickHandler`

Comment: oh yes that doesn't fire either, but without that and with the conditional element in front the alert repeatedly pops up without pressing the click